# Scroll from corner to corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I was wondering how to do a scroll from the left-top corner to the right-bottom corner.

From top to bottom is default.

```
$(function() {

   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

      event.preventDefault();

   });

});
```

How can I make it scroll from corner to corner?

Comment: Ehm, use `scrollTop` too? I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/mXwbT/

Comment: Problem is when window isnt cube isnt work it properly.. So any other suggestions @san its great but when u for example do width 300px in the end it does not match

Comment: here are another 3 examples I found if they are of any use http://jsfiddle.net/t0nyh0/8QTYt/36/ and another one http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/K4YSq/ and http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/